# Kubernetes Java API for Kubectl copy command

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, google-kubernetes-engine

I have a container running inside Kubernetes cluster (within POD) along side many other containers (in their own PODs) and my container is a common container. Now, I want to pull (copy) the files from other containers to my common container. I investigated for some options and found that kubectl copy can be used. But, for that, I need to include kubectl command line tool inside my common container. I'm not sure if this is right approach. So, I thought of using Java Kubernetes APIs to do the same. 
Is there equivalent Kubernetes REST API for Kubectl copy command ? I gone through the kubernetes APIs and could not find any such API ..

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

That's because [`kubectl cp` is implemented via `tar`](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/v1.9.6/pkg/kubectl/cmd/cp.go#L42-L43), so what is *actually* happening is `kubectl exec $pod -- tar -cf - /the/container/file | tar -xf -`, which is what I would expect your Java API would need to do, as well.

However, you may -- depending on your needs -- be able to get away with how I used to do it before `kubectl cp` arrived: `kubectl exec $pod -- /bin/cat /the/container/file > local-file` which in your circumstance may be a ton easier since I would expect the API would materialize those bytes as an `InputStream`, saving you the need to get into the tar-format-parsing business

Answer (score 1):

I think you should be able to do this using [Fabric8 Kubernetes Java Client](https://github.com/fabric8io/kubernetes-client). I would divide this into two tasks:

1. Copy specified file from your container(`c1`) to your local system
2. Copy file saved to your local system to your other container (say `c2`)

Let's say your have a pod running inside Kubernetes with two containers `c1` and `c2`. Let's take this as an example:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: multi-container-pod
spec:
  containers:
  - name: c1
    image: nginx:1.19.2
    ports:
    - containerPort: 80  
  - name: c2
    image: alpine:3.12
    command: ["watch", "wget", "-qO-", "localhost"]
```

Now I want to transfer a file `/docker-entrypoint.sh` in `c1` to `/tmp/docker-entrypoint.sh` in `c2`. [Fabric8 Kubernetes Client](https://github.com/fabric8io/kubernetes-client) provides fluent DSL to uploading/downloading files from Kubernetes Pods. As @mndanial already pointed out in his answer, copy operation involves encoding/decoding, Fabric8 relies on [`commons-codec`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/) and [`commons-compress`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/). These are optional dependencies and need to be included in your classpath in order to use copy operations. For maven, it would be adding it to `pom.xml` like this:

```xml
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
            <version>${commons-codec.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-compress</artifactId>
            <version>${commons-compress.version}</version>
        </dependency>
```

**Copying File from Container `c1` to your local system:**
In order to copy you can use `KubernetesClient`'s fluent DSL to specify which file to copy and where to copy in your local system. Here is example code:

```java
try (KubernetesClient client = new DefaultKubernetesClient()) {
    // Path Where to copy file to local storage
    Path downloadToPath = new File("/home/rohaan/Downloads/docker-entrypoint.sh").toPath();
    // Using Kubernetes Client to copy file from pod
    client.pods()
            .inNamespace("default")             // <- Namespace of pod
            .withName("multi-container-pod")    // <- Name of pod
            .inContainer("c1")                  // <- Container from which file has to be downloaded
            .file("/docker-entrypoint.sh")      // <- Path of file inside pod
            .copy(downloadToPath);              // <- Local path where to copy downloaded file
}
```

**Copying File from your local system to other Container (`c2`):**
Now we have to do the opposite of first step, similar to `copy()` `KubernetesClient` offers `upload()` method which allows you to upload file or directories to your target Pod. Here is how you would do it:

```java
try (KubernetesClient client = new DefaultKubernetesClient()) {
    // File which was downloaded in Step 1
    File fileToUpload = new File("/home/rohaan/Downloads/docker-entrypoint.sh");
    client.pods().inNamespace("default")
            .withName("multi-container-pod")
            .inContainer("c2")
            .file("/tmp/docker-entrypoint.sh")  // <- Target location in other container
            .upload(fileToUpload.toPath());     // <- Local path of downloaded file
}
```

When I executed this, I was able to see my file being copied in desired location:

```sh
~ : $ kubectl exec multi-container-pod -c c2 ls /tmp
docker-entrypoint.sh
```

[Fabric8 Kubernetes Client](https://github.com/fabric8io/kubernetes-client) also allows you to read a file as `InputStream` directly rather than storing it. Here is an example:

```java
try (KubernetesClient client = new DefaultKubernetesClient()) {
    try (InputStream is = client.pods()
            .inNamespace("default")
            .withName("quarkus-84dc4885b-tsck6")
            .inContainer("quarkus")
            .file("/tmp/jobExample.yml").read())  {
        String result = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is)).lines().collect(Collectors.joining("\n"));
        System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```